# How to change C++ Model from QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a list view in Qml with Text Input as one of the element. I used c++ model to inflate the list view . Now I want to change the C++ model if user enters any value in Text Input in qml.

How can I do that?

Comment: With "model", you mean `QAbstractItemModel`? I ask because you can do C++ models for QML very much simpler in some cases.

Comment: yes, I derived the model class from QAbstractItemModel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to either create a slot in your model class and invoke it:

```
public slots:
  setDataInModel(const int index, const QVariant &value);
```

And invoke it from the qml delegate of that element when it has been edited like this:

```
model.setDataInModel(index, text)
```

You can also create methods that are Q_INVOKABLE and call them from QML the same way.

Comment: I saw a method  setItemData ( const QModelIndex & index, const QMap<int, QVariant> & roles ) in QAbstractItemModel .I overide that method thinking of that it will be called once role data is changed from the QML. Is it not so ?

Comment: Unfortunately this method is not called automatically from QML you have to write slots or Q_INVOKABLE methods and call them yourself.